# setText("") at the edit text android error

Tags: android

i got problem when make edit text empty when a button clicked. The DDMS said it was error with uncaught exception group=0x4001b188.
here is y code

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    float fm_value_pdty;
    Button calc_fm_pdty, dt_pdty_calc, loader_pdty_calc;
    TextView fm_value_pdty_txt;
    EditText DT_count, Loader_count;
    public EditText DT_Pdty;
    public EditText Loader_Pdty;
    public static float vdtpdty;
    public static float vloaderpdty;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fm_value_pdty=(float) 0;
        calc_fm_pdty = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcpdty);
        dt_pdty_calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcpdty_dt);
        loader_pdty_calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcpdty_loader);
        fm_value_pdty_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fm_pdty_value);
        DT_Pdty = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.DTPdty_ET);
        Loader_Pdty = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Loader_CT_ET);
        vdtpdty=(float) 0.0;
        vloaderpdty=(float) 0.0;


        calc_fm_pdty.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //if (DT_CT.getText().toString() <>""){
                    if ((DT_Pdty.getText().toString()!=null) &&  (Loader_Pdty.getText().toString()!=null))  {
                        fm_value_pdty = ((float) Integer.parseInt(DT_Pdty.getText().toString()))/((float) Integer.parseInt(Loader_Pdty.getText().toString()));
                        fm_value_pdty_txt.setText("Fleet Matching value is " + fm_value_pdty);
                    }
                    else if ((DT_Pdty.getText().toString()==null) ||  (Loader_Pdty.getText().toString()==null)) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                        dlgAlert.setMessage("Please input the DT Productivty and Loader Productivty");
                        dlgAlert.setTitle("Data is empty");
                        dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK",null);
                        dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
                        dlgAlert.create().show();
                    }
            }
        });
        dt_pdty_calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dt_pdty.vloaderpdty=vloaderpdty;
                DT_Pdty.setText("");
                Loader_Pdty.setText("");
                Intent pdty = new Intent(Main.this, dt_pdty.class);
                startActivity(pdty);
                DT_Pdty.setText(Float.toString(vdtpdty));
                Loader_Pdty.setText(Float.toString(vloaderpdty));
            }
        });
        loader_pdty_calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v2) {
                ld_pdty.vdtpdty=vdtpdty;
                DT_Pdty.setText("");
                Loader_Pdty.setText("");
                Intent pdty = new Intent(Main.this, ld_pdty.class);
                startActivity(pdty);
                DT_Pdty.setText(Float.toString(vdtpdty));
                Loader_Pdty.setText(Float.toString(vloaderpdty));
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

the code is simple when i try to activate an activity with a button first the edit text is emptied and that activity start and after the activity finish the edit text that has emptied is fill with calculated value from the activity.
i want to make a program that has two edit text and two button. the first edit text will be filled with result from first button and same as the other edit text and button. the problem that i get result for first button but when i run second activity from second button i get an error. from the logcat it is because the view of first edit text. i already updated my post with logcat.

```
08-20 19:52:47.924: D/AndroidRuntime(237): Shutting down VM
08-20 19:52:47.958: W/dalvikvm(237): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
08-20 19:52:47.958: E/AndroidRuntime(237): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at com.example.fleetmatcher.Main$2.onClick(Main.java:66)
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6541)
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
08-20 19:52:48.028: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-20 19:52:48.201: I/dalvikvm(237): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
08-20 19:52:48.422: I/dalvikvm(237): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-20 19:52:50.620: I/Process(237): Sending signal. PID: 237 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Is there a java file named `ld_pdty` in your project i.e a class named `ld_pdty`?

Comment: yes. an android activity if i might add.

Comment: Why you have referenced/created 3 buttons when you require only 2? Why `calc_fm_pdty`,`dt_pdty_calc`,`loader_pdty_calc` these 3 buttons?You need only 2 buttons right?

Answer (score 0):

why do you do this

```
EditText Loader_Pdty; why not EditText loader_Pdty;
```

and convert your float to string before adding to the string to settext do this

```
fm_value_pdty = ((float) Integer.parseInt(DT_Pdty.getText().toString()))/((float) Integer.parseInt(Loader_Pdty.getText().toString()));
fm_value_pdty_txt.setText("Fleet Matching value is " + String.valueOf(fm_value_pdty));
```

now precaution time

```
dt_pdty_calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Dt_pdty.vloaderpdty=vloaderpdty; ///change the first letter
            dT_Pdty.setText(""); // change the firstx letter..
            Loader_Pdty.setText("");
            Intent pdty = new Intent(Main.this, Dt_pdty.class); //change the first letter
            startActivity(pdty);
            DT_Pdty.setText(Float.toString(vdtpdty));
            Loader_Pdty.setText(Float.toString(vloaderpdty));
        }
    });
    loader_pdty_
```

try that..let me know if it helps

Comment: ok thanks for help. but that is not the error. the error is when i set the edit text to empty. how can i get reset the edit text?

Comment: look at your code very well, you name prefix of classes with lowercases and name prefix of variables with uppercases..jux change that for precaution..and see..and whats line 66 in your code @maraden

Comment: well, still error. and the logcat still say same problem.@Elltz